# Shortening Oracle record/cursor usage

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a set of entities in a table, like this:

```
PK      Entity_Name        Multiplier        Min_Period        Max_Period
01       No Mult              100               0                  12
02       5% Mult              105               12                 36
03       10% Mult             115               36                 100
```

I want to check an input against them and, depending on which period this input falls in, return the multiplier. Currently, my way of doing this is so convoluted and I'm sure there *must* be an easier way. My current method is to create a record and a cursor:

```
TYPE r_multipliers  IS RECORD (
    entity_name             VARCHAR2(100),
    multiplier              NUMBER(10),
    min_period              NUMBER(10),
    max_period              NUMBER(10)
);
TYPE t_multipliers IS TABLE OF r_multipliers
INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
my_rec r_multipliers;
l_multipliers t_multipliers;

CURSOR c_multipliers
IS
    SELECT entity_name, multiplier, min_period, max_period
    FROM multipliers;
```

I then loop through the cursor, to store each possible entity:

```
FOR record IN c_multipliers
LOOP
    my_rec.entity_name       := record.entity_name;
    my_rec.multiplier        := record.multiplier;
    my_rec.min_period        := record.min_period;
    my_rec.max_period        := record.max_period;
    l_multipliers(record.entity_name) := my_rec;
END LOOP;
```

Finally, I use this logic in a query, like so:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN [input] BETWEEN l_multipliers('No Mult').min_period AND l_multipliers('No Mult').max_period        
    THEN l_multipliers('No Mult').multiplier
    WHEN [input] BETWEEN l_multipliers('5% Mult').min_period AND l_multipliers('5% Mult').max_period        
    THEN l_multipliers('5% Mult').multiplier
    //etc (up to six or seven of these case statements)
```

Now, there is **so** much code being used here to do something that is obviously very simple. I'm very inexperienced with PL/SQL. I'm assuming I'm overcomplicating things massively. Can anyone suggest how to simplify **and** shorten this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one simple select statement, no PL/SQL needed:

```
select multiplier
from multipliers
where input between min_period and max_period;
```

Comment: The thing is, there will be multiple case statements, up to six or seven - I don't want to use multiple select statements

Comment: @Andrew With the minor glitch that you cannot use `between` here because of the semi-open interval, could you elaborate a little what's wrong with this solution? It will directly return the "right" multiplier, whatever is the number of case in your "entity table".

Comment: You're right. I'm an eejit, of course. Apologies. Head is just fried today. Of course this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 
  l_mult multipliers.entity_name%type;
  input_period multipliers.max_period%type;
begin 
  select multiplier into l_mult 
  from multipliers
  where input_period >= min_period
    and input_period < max_period;

  -- return l_mult;
exception 
    when no_data_found then
        -- do something
    when others then
        -- do something else
end;
```